# Input em HTML que pode guardar vários valores?

Tags: html, html5, formulário

Como posso fazer um input parecido com o daqui do fórum? 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask na área de tags, quando inserimos uma tag exemplo: "PHP", e damos enter ele já guarda aquele valor e espera mais um do usuário.

Comment: Já pensou em usar um plugin do jQuery ? o [**select2**](https://select2.github.io/) faz isso, olhe os [**exemplos**](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)!

Comment: Como já dito pelo @Brunno vai depender de como você está trabalhando. O `html` por si só não executa essa função. Você vai precisar trabalhar com javascript para obter o resultado. Seja através de jquery, ou de outro método de trabalho, mas vai precisar de uma outra programação para isso

Comment: Obrigado pela as respostas. Usei o plugin select2 e deu certo @Brunno, obrigado! Vi também que se usarmos o "multiple" no select dá certo, mas com esse plugin ficou melhor :p. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem JavaScript não será possível implementar. Sugiro utilizar um plugin jQuery como [**Select2**](https://select2.github.io/). Segue o link para pagina de [**exemplo**](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) e um exemplo básico:

HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="MG">Minas</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```